# multi select option for F4 help (Value List) in Table of an Object Page

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

SAP Fiori elements List-Report application build on top of CAP annotations doesn't allow multi-line input from search helps for a table. Entries can be added only one by one.

In Gregor's Wolf [Bookshop demo](https://github.com/gregorwolf/bookshop-demo) application there is a sample app [MaintainerGroup](http://localhost:4004/webapp/fiori-ui5-1.120.9.html?sap-language=en#MaintainerGroup-manage) to reproduce the behavior:

1. When Editing "Group" only one entry can be added at a time:
   [add new entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VRP1.png)
2. Employee selection from Search Help (value help):
   [select: Employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMbpe.png)

By adding standard [Multivalue/Multi](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.ui.mdc/sample/sap.ui.mdc.demokit.sample.MultiValueField) it is possible to select multiple values but only for a small list of values (<100 items) also only 200 items can be selected at a time. In case when more than 100 entries were selected and saved, value help dialog  on next opening will pick up only the first 100.

How to get multi select option similar to search help parameters in the List Report?
[multi select f4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnbri.png)